# QStackedWidget memory leak when adding QWidgets

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks, qt5, valgrind

I'm learning Qt (5.7.1) and I have created a simple application with two buttons. If you press button A, the screen with button B becomes visible. The opposite happens when button B is pressed.

When I test if I correctly destroyed every object, I came upon strange behaviour. Once a QWidget is added to a QStackedWidget, valgrind shows that I've definitely lost 4,480 bytes in 18 blocks, but I destroy every object that is created.

The [documentation for QStackedWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html) has a `removeWidget` method, but this doesn't solve the memory leaks.

```
==2265== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2265==     in use at exit: 238,228 bytes in 4,113 blocks
==2265==   total heap usage: 49,518 allocs, 45,405 frees, 5,951,803 bytes allocated
==2265== 
==2265== LEAK SUMMARY:
==2265==    definitely lost: 4,480 bytes in 18 blocks
==2265==    indirectly lost: 1,377 bytes in 65 blocks
==2265==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2265==    still reachable: 232,371 bytes in 4,030 blocks
==2265==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <app.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        QApplication a(argc, argv);
        app program;
        program.show();
        return a.exec();
}
```

**app.h**

```
#ifndef TEST_APP
#define TEST_APP

#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QBoxLayout>
#include <QStackedWidget>
#include <QPushButton>

class app : public QWidget {
        Q_OBJECT
private:
        QHBoxLayout    *layout;
        QStackedWidget *sites;

        QWidget        *window_a;
        QHBoxLayout    *layout_a;
        QPushButton    *button_a;

        QWidget        *window_b;
        QHBoxLayout    *layout_b;
        QPushButton    *button_b;
public:
        app();
        ~app();
};

#endif // TEST_APP
```

**app.cpp**

```
#include <app.h>

app::app() : QWidget(0) {
        QSize window_size(80, 80);
        layout   = new QHBoxLayout(this);
        sites    = new QStackedWidget();

        window_a = new QWidget();
        layout_a = new QHBoxLayout();
        button_a = new QPushButton("Button A", window_a);

        window_b = new QWidget();
        layout_b = new QHBoxLayout();
        button_b = new QPushButton("Button B", window_b);

        sites->resize(window_size);
        sites->setMaximumSize(window_size);
        sites->setMinimumSize(window_size);
        layout->addWidget(sites);

        window_a->setLayout(layout_a);
        layout_a->addWidget(button_a);
        sites->addWidget(window_a);

        window_b->setLayout(layout_b);
        layout_b->addWidget(button_b);
        sites->addWidget(window_b);

        sites->setCurrentIndex(0);

        connect(button_a, &QPushButton::clicked, this, [this] { sites->setCurrentIndex(1); });
        connect(button_b, &QPushButton::clicked, this, [this] { sites->setCurrentIndex(0); });
}

app::~app() {
        delete button_a;
        delete button_b;
        button_a = button_b = nullptr;

        delete layout_a;
        delete layout_b;
        layout_a = layout_b = nullptr;

        delete window_a;
        delete window_b;

        delete sites;
        delete layout;
}
```

**test.pro**

```
QT += core gui widgets
CONFIG += c++14
TARGET = test
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
QMAKE_CFLAGS += -g
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp app.cpp
HEADERS += app.h
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
FORMS +=
```

Comment: For information, you don't have to explicitly destroy the widgets in your `app`'s destructor. If the widgets are properly parented, Qt manages their destruction itself.

Comment: Looks like false positives at a glance.  Use a proper suppression file for valgrind.

Comment: Also, you don't have to use pointers at least for the question code, just put the widgets as member variables. They will be destructed before QObject destructor is reached, so they remove themselves and QObject doesn't try to delete them then. This is slightly more efficient (less heap allocation overhead).

Comment: Valgrind has a setting to show details of the lost blocks. If you don't have that on, turn it on and see if it helps pinpoint the problem. If the memory loss is truly buried in a Qt class, that at least tells you it's not your problem to deal with.

Comment: Also, Qt 5.7 is not maintained anymore. If the memory leak is a Qt bug, it might have been solved in one of the later versions.

Comment: Qt 5.12.3 has this problem as well. If I add `--leak-check=full` to valgrind, it shows the blocks are lost due to some font mechanism in Qt.

Comment: Write new QWidget(this); new QPushButton(this); instead new QWidget(); new QPushButton(); and for all others.